# iOS - Understanding NSLayoutConstraint multiplier

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set the height of a view according to my View Controller's height. This is my code.

```
self.view.addConstraints([
            self.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.topAnchor),
            self.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.leftAnchor),
            self.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.rightAnchor),
            self.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 20.0, constant: 0.0)
            ])
```

I want `someView` 's height to be 20% of the View Controller's total height. The result I got now is incorrect. `someView` 's height doesn't change when ever I change the multiplier.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

0.2 shows incorrect result. Someview appeared larger than View Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the parameter incorrectly.  20 means you want view's height to be 20 times bigger than  someView's height.  What you want is view to be 20% of someView's hieght, so you need to multiply by .2.

```
    self.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0.0)
```

Comment: 0.2 shows incorrect result. Someview appeared larger than View Controller

Comment: I didn't realize view is supposed to be the view controller. reverse the constraints: someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0.0). traditionally you express new constraints as a relation of the subview to the superview.